# react redux not displaying the correct data

Tags: reactjs, rest, redux, webapi, react-fullstack

i've taken a few courses on react and redux and so far the challenges are still piling up.  i'm creating a simple app were at the time i need to just map the response from the api, but the state looks weird.  the actions is returning the data, but is being displayed awkward.  Please see the images attached.  Does anyone know why the console.log of the data returns a number instead of an object or array name?  also if you see the state from the redux dev tools, you can see that where an object name would be displayed, you see undefined instead.  Please help.  I've been at it for a couple of days and have been banging my head against the wall.  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5lb9.png)

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
reducer
import _ from 'lodash';

import { 
FETCH_CLIENT,
FETCH_CLIENTS,
ADD_CLIENTS_COMMENTS
} from "../actions/types";

export default (state = {}, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
case FETCH_CLIENT:
  return { ...state, ..._.mapKeys(action.payload, 'ClientUno') };
case FETCH_CLIENTS:
  return { ...state, [action.payload.ClientUno]: action.payload };
case ADD_CLIENTS_COMMENTS:
    return { ...state, [action.payload.ClientUno]: action.payload }; 
default:
  return state;
}
 };
 
combined reducer
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import ClientsReducer from "./ClientsReducer";

export default combineReducers({
clients:ClientsReducer
});

action
const mapStateToProps = state => {
return{
    clients:Object.values(state.clients),
}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{fetchAllClients})(Clients);
```

after removing .ClientUno.  This my new state

[image]

post man response attached[image]

Comment: Really hard to say what's going on without seeing actual code. Can you please post the relevant reducer logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your reducer logic is wrong:

```js
return { ...state, [action.payload.ClientUno]: action.payload }
```

Per the screenshots, your `action.payload` is an array of items.  The individual *items* do have a `.ClientUno` field inside them.  But the *array* most definitely will not.  So, `action.payload.ClientUno` is indeed `undefined`, and that's what you're using as a key.

You'll need to rethink what you want to use as a key there.  I don't know how you're actually trying to structure this slice state, so I can't provide a suggestion there.

I *will* note that the Redux patterns you're using here are very outdated.  "Modern Redux" with Redux Toolkit is much simpler and easier to use - there's no `"ACTION_TYPES"`, switch statements, or object spreads.  Please see our official Redux docs tutorials to learn how to use Redux Toolkit:

https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index

Comment: i tried the new approach first with the toolkit and the result was the same.  This was a cry for help cause it just did not make any sense.

Comment: The real problem here is the use of `action.payload.ClientUno`.  **That field _does not exist_!**  You can't use it, no matter whether you're writing the reducer logic by hand, or using RTK.

Comment: when i remove that field my new state looks like the attached.

Comment: the data comes out of the api normal.  i've also attached a postman response

Comment: @Thecruz : Your response data is an array. That's fine - that's typically what comes back from an API request like "list some items".  So, your reducer needs to deal with that data as if it's an array, not as if it's an object. Looking at the last Redux DevTools screenshot, that seems to be what it's doing now.  Is there some other problem still?

Comment: you were right.  that line of code was the culprit.  i've replaced it with the following for anyone who may have the same issue.  return { ...state, ..._.mapKeys(action.payload, 'CLIENT_UNO') };